# How to read a image file from the WWW directory phonegap (IOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Basicly I want to read/get an image file (jpg)  from the /WWW/images/ directory in phonegap for IOS5/6
but I can't access to them.

It's seems to be a simple task but I can't do It, it's frustrating

This is programed into a virtual machine and is played from a simulator.

this is my code.

```
function first(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0,gotFS,fail1);

}
function gotFS(fileSystem){
    console.log("gotFS__");
    fileSystem.root.getFile("images/faq.jpg",null,gotFileEntry,fail1);
}
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
     console.log("gotFileEntry___");
    fileEntry.file(gotFile,fail1);
}
function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
}
function readDataUrl(file){
     console.log("readDataUrl___");
    var reader =  new Filereader();
    reader.onloadend=function(evt){
        console.log("read as data URL");
        console.log("result:"+evt.target.result);


        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
function fail1(evt){
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

there is no error report. but nothing happens
where is my mistake?
please help Me.
best regards

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution, in my case I want to open a pdf file located in www/library/pdffiles/file.pdf.

```
   var path = window.location.pathname;
   var phoneGapPath =  path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
   var resource = phoneGapPath + "/pdffiles/"+ localFileName;
   window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage( resource );
```

I hope someone will serve if they have the same problem.

Comment: to get some errors to report, use a try-catch. Then `alert(error.message)` in the `catch(error){}` part

Comment: the error is always the same 
NOT_FOUND_ERR

Comment: I have this problem also. So far, I've found that fileSystem.root returns the Documents folder for the iOS app (which is by default empty), not the www folder. That's why there's always a NOT_FOUND_ERR. I'll update you when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

I found the solution, in my case I want to open a pdf file located in www/library/pdffiles/file.pdf.

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var phoneGapPath =  path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var resource = phoneGapPath + "/pdffiles/"+ localFileName;
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage( resource );
```

I hope someone will serve if they have the same problem.